# Kotlin: pass array to varargs method with spread operator

Tags: kotlin, dagger-2, android-room

I spent far too long trying to work out how to pass a number of `Migration` instances to a `Room` database builder for a Dagger2 module.

The Room database builder requires context and the database name.

```
Room.databaseBuilder(context, Database::class.java, dbName)
                .build()
```

Migrations can be added to the builder with the `addMigrations` method which takes `vararg migrations: Migration!`

One option is to create the builder.

```
val builder = Room.databaseBuilder(context, Database::class.java, dbName)
```

And then forEach through the migrations

```
migrations.forEach { builder.addMigrations(it) }
```

however this is messy and unnecessary, and the spread operator should be used instead.

I managed to miss this as the only documentation I found for the spread operator was a single sentence in the docs.

> When we call a vararg-function, we can pass arguments one-by-one, e.g. asList(1, 2, 3), or, if we already have an array and want to pass its contents to the function, we use the spread operator (prefix the array with *)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Varargs Kotlin Java interop not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32600931/varargs-kotlin-java-interop-not-working-properly)

Comment: What is your actual question?

Answer (score 4):

In order to pass the array to the function. The array just needs to be prefixed with an asterisk `*`.

```
val migrations: Array<Migration>
Room.databaseBuilder(context, Database::class.java, dbName)
                .addMigrations(*migrations)
                .build()
```

In general if we have

```
fun foo(vararg things: Type) {
    //Do something with the things
}
```

We can call `foo` with `arrayOf`, or with an `Array`.

```
foo(*Array(n, { it.toType()}))
foo(*arrayOf(instance1, instance2, instance3))
val array = Array<Type>(n, {it.toType()})
foo(*array)
```

Comment: the documentation already mentioned spread operator [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#java-varargs) and [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#variable-number-of-arguments-varargs). so publish it here is unnecessary.

Comment: I saw the second link. What I was looking for, and didn't see originally, was an explanation like https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/kotlin/5835/vararg-parameters-in-functions#t=201707102023489184168 this, explaining what the spread is doing rather than just saying "stick an asterisk before your" argument. I also wanted to find out if there is a particular reason for having the operator, rather than automatically spreading any array passed to a vararg method.

Comment: Hi, there is a demo about `asList` at the bottom in the second link. :)

Comment: I did see it. Thinking about the reason for the operator, I suppose if I have `vararg things: Any` and pass an array to it, it is not clear whether the array is a single argument, or the array contents are individual arguments, which is why an explicit `*` operator is required. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Hi, the `asList` function signature is already tell you that will spreads all array elements into the parameters one-by-one. in short: `arrayOf(1,*arrayOf(2),3)` is equivalent to `arrayOf(1,2,3)`.